# jQuery: generate link from table cell contents

Tags: jquery, html

I have a nice table

```
<table id="#table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo1</td>
    <td class="column2">#bar1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo2</td>
    <td class="column2">#bar2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to select the second column and replace the content with links, using the values in the td's for href's. So the end result should be:

```
<table id="#table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo1</td>
    <td class="column2"><a href="#bar1">link</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo2</td>
    <td class="column2"><a href="#bar2">link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I select the td and wrap it with a nice a href.

```
$("td.column2").wrapInner(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.nodeValue + "'></a>";
});
```

This however, generates this:

```
<table id="#table1">
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo1</td>
    <td class="column2"><a href="null">#bar1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">foo2</td>
    <td class="column2"><a href="null">#bar2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm probably overlooking something ridiculously simple, but it's been a long day. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not use `#` in ids. You are mixing CSS grammar into your html.  The `#` in CSS is equivalent to `id=` in html. To reference an element by id in CSS when the id contains the `#` character (eg, `id="#table1"`), you would need to escape the hash: `#\#table1 { }` see [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J8nHK/)

```
$("td.column2").html(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + "'>Link</a>";
});
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J8nHK/1)

if you want link text to be same as previous text

```
$("td.column2").html(function() {
    return "<a href='" + this.innerHTML + "'>"+this.innerHTML+" </a>";
});
```

References

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: That's spot on. Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: I ended up using `$("td.column2").html(function() {
    return "<a href='" + $(this).html() + "'>Link</a>";
});` as per other people's suggestions. Thanks everyone for your quick help!

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$("td.column2").html(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    return $('<a>',{
        href: self.text(),
        text: 'link'
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/V4dFj/

Comment: +1 for use of {params} (which I didn't know of). That implies a better readability.

Comment: @Austin I don't see where op wants to keep the contents. In his example it is entirely replaced.

Comment: @Austin, no he doesn't. He wants `#bar1` and `#bar2` to become `link`. But he uses the wrong method for this and so besides not creating the correct link he keeps the existing text as the text of the link..

Comment: Ah, his use of `wrapInner` threw me off

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery as well to get the value of your td... (it's just more coherent to use jQuery when you can), which is its text :

First piece of answer : replace `this.nodeValue` with `$(this).text()`.

Second piece of answer : I think **you are using `wrapInner()` wrong**. See http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/ What you want to do is replacing the inner content of your td. So you should actually use `$('td.column2').html(function() { // etc }) ;`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td.column2').html(function(i,h){
    var text = $(this).text();
    return '<a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a>';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aYLgA/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/p68pH/

```
$(function() {

    $("td.column2").wrapInner(function() {
    return "<a href='" + $(this).html() + "'></a>";
    });

});
```

Comment: This echos the href value together with the link name. So it displays <a href="bar1#">Link bar1#</a>

Comment: your question was to display the table cell content in a link. Not removing special characters.